# How to validate a string with over long UTF-8 encoded character?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have a security concern over my application converting 
`Request : gxwi8nijmg[0xc1][0x81]g3mredhcuo` to `Response : gxwi8nijmgAg3mredhcuo`.

How to restrict over-long UTF-8 character encoding on jersey with Jackson JSON Binding, or a jersey validation interceptor filter checking the request for overlong UTF-8 character be a best fit. In either case how to validate a string with over long UTF-8 encoded character?